# Is there a way to temporarily remove PyInstaller's nonconsole option?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I build my code using the nonconsole option when distributing my tools to users:

```
pyinstaller test.py --noconsole
```

Because without a console the look is simpler and more beautiful.

However, when an error occurs in the user's environment, there is no way to know the content of the error if it is a nonconsole.

I want to switch between console and non-console after building code.

I want to hide the console normally, so that the console can be displayed only when switching to error checking mode.

Isn't that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is possible - hiding/showing the console is a compile/build option, rather than a run time one.

Have you considered using the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module? 
This will give you an easy way to log messages to a file, which you can inspect if something goes wrong.